# ActionbarSherlock doesn't appear

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having problem with ActionBar Sherlock (latest version), after successful compilation I don't see ActionBar in app. Just black screen and default TextView... 
Before I've a problem with install libraries, but after added Support Library to ActionBarSherlock I can built it.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
```

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `android:targetSdkVersion` is set to 11 or higher in your manifest.

Comment: @max_dev: Here is a basic app showing the use of ActionBarSherlock: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo -- see what is different about how I did it and what you have.

Comment: I got it! When you create new Android Project, don't forget change properties of project (Properties->Android->Build Target: Android 4.0) and below add library.